# Need dynamic VBA formula

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula

I am trying to put in a dynamic formula for named variables a and b. The formula would contain this logic: If a  (defined below) is blank then b (defined below) else a. The results should be entered into a new column called Client ID. I was able to create the new column Client ID but am having trouble with the formula where the code stops since it needs to be debugged. 
I have tried to define my variables and ranges differently but still have issues.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
Sub baSTEP1formulaINDEV()

'A column named Client ID already exists

   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim StartCell As Range
   Dim LastR As Long
   Dim LastC As Long

   Set sht = Worksheets("Group Activity")
   Set StartCell = Range("A1")

 Dim a As Integer
    a = Cells.Find(What:="*Client: Client / Contact ID*", After:=Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column
    ActiveWindow.Activate

  Dim b As Integer
    b = Cells.Find(What:="*Case Participant Client ID*", After:=Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column
    ActiveWindow.Activate

 'Find Last Row and Column
  LastR = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastC = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range(Selection).Formula = _
"=IF(ISBLANK(a),b,a)"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic formula you better use function() instead of sub(), this solution may be help you: in this case you just enter your custom formula in any cell you want, for example you can enter this formula in cell E1: `=customSearch(A1:B4)` the Range `A1:B4` (for example) could be select by mouse drag

```
 Function customSearch(SearchRange As Range) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aFound As Boolean, bFound As Boolean
    Dim aText, bText
    Dim aAddress, bAddress
    aText = "*Client: Client / Contact ID*"
    bText = "*Case Participant Client ID*"
    aFound = False
    bFound = False
    
    For Each rng In SearchRange
        If InStr(rng, aText) > 0 Then
            aAddress = rng.Address
            aFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If aFound = False Then
        For Each rng In SearchRange
            If InStr(rng, bText) > 0 Then
                bAddress = rng.Address
                bFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    
    If aFound = True Then
        customSearch = aAddress
    Else
        customSearch = bAddress
    End If
End Function
```

this comment may be helpful for feature.

You can set your function in public  and save your file with type "*.xla" (Excel Add-in) and then you can use this function in every workbook you want.

Comment: Thank you for leading me down the right path with Function. I will still need to edit this since I want the function to be completely dynamic and not have to select any of the cells by dragging. Ideally, I'd like the function to search across the dataset and enter the values under the new column all the way to the last row by just clicking Run. I am trying to test what you suggested but cannot get it to run just yet.

Comment: sure, you can use `ActiveSheet.Cells` instead of  `SearchRange` then you don't need to select any range. in addition you can set `SearchRange`  AS `Optional` in function arguments so you can enter that or leave that. like this : `customSearch(Optional SearchRange As Range)`

Comment: I was not able to get this to work even after making the changes you suggested, unfortunately. Excel freezes each time I run it. I thank you for your suggestion and will keep trying so that I can give you credit if it does work.